# Infinite loop when entering a password

Tags: c++, string, validation, passwords, infinite-loop

I'm trying to make this password verify program, and im getting an infinite loop at the first while. Its very frustrating. I've been working on this for about a day and half...
The purpose of the program is to assure the pass is at least 6 chars long and has one upper, one lower, and one digit as well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;


bool testPass(char []);
int main()
{
    char *password;
    int length; 
    int num; 

    cout << "Please enter how many characters you would like your\npassword to be.";
    cout << " Your password must be at least 6 characters long." << endl;
    cin >> num;


     while(num < 6)
     {
        cout << "Please enter a password length of at least 6 characters." << endl;
        cin >> num;
     }


    password = new char[num+1]; 


    cout << "Please enter a password that contains at least one uppercase letter, ";
    cout << "one\nlowercase letter, and at least one digit." << endl;


    cin >> password;


    length = strlen(password);



    while (length != num)
    {
        cout << "Your password is not the size you requested. ";
        cout << "Please re-enter your password." << endl;
        cin >> password;
        length = strlen(password);
    }

    if (testPass(password))
        cout << "Your password is valid." << endl;
    else
    {
        cout << "Your password is not valid. ";
        cout << "Please refer to the above warning message." << endl;
    }

    delete[] password;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}



bool testPass(char pass[])
{
    bool aUpper = false,
         aLower = false,
         aDigit = false ;
    for ( int i = 0 ; pass[i] ; ++i )
        if ( isupper(pass[i]) )
            aUpper = true ;
        else if ( islower(pass[i]) )
            aLower = true ;
        else if ( isdigit(pass[i]) )
            aDigit = true ;
    if ( aUpper && aLower && aDigit )
        return true;
    else
        return false ;
}
```

Comment: You obviously need to specify a number greater than 5. Attach a debugger, it helps a lot!

Comment: Are you entering the password at first prompt ?
You need to enter a number>6 first

Comment: I think it's your improper use of "num". You should try creating a string, and have it do `while (string.length() < 6)` with `cin >> string`;

Comment: The best case scenario is fine: http://ideone.com/tK98vx

Comment: how do I attach a debugger?

Comment: why bother asking that? just set your password length requirement to be between 6 and X. predefine password length to X+1

Comment: i figured out my mistake, i guess i wasnt paying attention, anywho thanks guy

Comment: @bigdog225 The code is correct, your input was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
int num; 
cin >> num;
```

The code above will ask for a number and store it in num. This is not what you want, you will need to store the password in a string, and check the length and other properties if required.

```
cin >> str;
```

stops reading as soon as if finds any blank space character, and this is not what we want.

Please have a look at http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/

The solution could be the following code:

```
string password;
bool valid = false;

while (!valid) {
    getline(cin, password);
    valid = password_valid(password);
    if (!valid) {
        // display error message
    }
}

// password is valid
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want at least 6 characters long, you need `<=` so you while loop should be 
`while(num <= 6)`.